# R data frame: How to control the conversion of matrix containing scientific notation strings to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a string matrix where the fields were derived from numbers in scientific notation. I want to convert the character matrix to a data frame and work on the numeric fields. During the matrix to data frame conversion R converts the strings to factors, maybe because of the 'e' character in the middle of the number. If the stringAsFactors() option is set to FALSE, the columns will be left as character, so still not numeric.

For example:

```
> m
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "1e-07" "4e-06"
[2,] "2e-05" "5e-05"
[3,] "0.03"  "1e-07"
> data.frame(m)
     X1    X2
1 1e-07 4e-06
2 2e-05 5e-05
3  0.03 1e-07
> class(data.frame(m))
[1] "data.frame"
> df = data.frame(m) 
> df
     X1    X2
1 1e-07 4e-06
2 2e-05 5e-05
3  0.03 1e-07
> class(df$X1)
[1] "factor"
> class(df$X2)
[1] "factor"
```

How can I force the data frame to interpret these strings as numbers? data.matrix() does actually convert string in scientific notation to numeric, but I want to know if there is a way to control the character matrix to data frame conversion directly, without going through the intermediate data.matrix() conversion step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change it into a numeric matrix first, *then* make a data.frame of it.

```
# A string matrix
m <- matrix(as.character(runif(6)),3)

# as.data.frame doesn't turn it into numbers...
str(as.data.frame(m)) # factors
str(as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) # strings

d <- m
# Make it numeric first
mode(d) <- "numeric"

# Now turn it into a data.frame...
d <- as.data.frame(d)
str(d) # numeric

str(m) # still strings...
```

...but it would be better if you could avoid storing the matrix values as strings in the first place! Unless you loaded them from a file, there shouldn't be any reason to. If you happened to get them as strings from some other operation, you should look back at that operation and see how you can avoid losing the numeric mode.

Comment: Yep, that's what I do using data.matrix(). Is there a way to avoid the matrix conversion step? The data frame conversion does convert string digits to numeric when there isn't scientific notation involved.

Comment: ...You need to provide an example of this. I can't reproduce that. I updated the example above - and there isn't scientific notation involved. `as.data.frame` still makes factor or string columns...

Comment: @RobertKubrick - You *need* to do what I did in my answer above. `data.frame` or `as.data.frame` will **never** turn your strings into numeric values. I updated the answer to show how to keep the old matrix around.

Comment: Right, I thought data.frame() would convert regular digit strings to numbers, but it doesn't. Everything gets converted to factors. I am working with xts objects and need to perform numerical operations on the time-series, that's how I end up with the character matrix.

Comment: @RobertKubrick - But xts objects are numeric (with a class), so it seems your conversion *to* strings is the real problem.

Comment: The problem is that the original data frame has a mix of character and numeric fields and the xts object I create becomes a character matrix. I think this happens because xts wants to keep all field values, else it would have to convert the strings to NAs.

Comment: @RobertKubrick - I don't know much about `xts`, but it seems you should have cleaned the original data.frame (e.g. removed the character columns), before converting to xts.